# Reduce: Var is not a valid variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and persisting through 13.1 or later. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

I am trying to integrate the following but it returns a `Reduce::ivar` warning message.

```
Integrate[qT^(1 + x) * Exp[- qT y^n  ]* 1/qT^2, 
          {qT, 0, ∞},  GenerateConditions -> False]
```

[image]

Although it correctly does the integration, I don't understand the message. Is it some kind of bug introduced in the version `12.3.1.0` on the Linux kernel?

Comment: The same error on MMA `13.0.1` in wolfram cloud.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report it to Wolfram.

Comment: Bug report filed

Comment: The same error on MMA `13.0.1` in Wolfram Desktop.

Comment: The result is correct though.

Comment: An interesting old bug. It can be seen even in version **8.0.4**, but version **5.2** is free of it.

Comment: Fixed in 13.2.0.